# Cannot find module "laravel-echo"

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am learning to configure Laravel Echo Socket.js and **[following an article here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo)**

Code in bootstrap.js is below

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

When I run the above code, it says, Cannot find module "laravel-echo"

I am not using pusher and redis. In the above reference page, I think, there is no installation guidelines given for only socket.io

Can somebody explain if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to install below packages.

```
npm install -g laravel-echo-server
```

**[then following the step by step instruction as give here](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)**

Finally put below code before any js file.

```
<script src="http://{{ Request::getHost() }}:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 11):

I solved the same problem installing the following packages:

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue is here:-

import Echo from **"laravel-echo"**

you will write it as:-

import Echo from **'laravel-echo';**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You're saying to use single quotes instead of double quotes when js accepts both? Or are you saying to add a semicolon when they are optional in js?