# Laravel Echo server responds nothing in browser

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, laravel-echo

I am following the tutorial given in https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-echo-server-how-to-24d5778ece8b .

I installed `laravel-echo-server`, `redis`, `socket.io`, `laravel-echo`.

This is the configuration of `laravel-echo-server init`

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

This js code is at the bottom of `app.blade.php` which is included in all pages

```
<script type="module">
    import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

    window.io = require('socket.io-client');window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
    });

    window.Echo.channel('test-event')
        .listen('ExampleEvent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
</script>
```

I created an event `php artisan make:event ExampleEvent` as follows

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ExampleEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('test-event');
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'data' => 'Hi bro!'
        ];
    }
}
```

and the following route

```
Route::get('test-broadcast', function(){
    broadcast(new \App\Events\ExampleEvent);
});
```

I also started a queue listener

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries=1
```

When I visit the page `test-broadcast` I see this in terminal

[image]

But the console of the browser shows nothing while the `console.log(e);` must return something. I also did this

```
    window.Echo.channel('test-event')
        .listen('ExampleEvent', (e) => {
            alert('hi')
            console.log(e);
        });
```

but nothing was alerted. It seems something is wrong with listening.

Thanks in advance.

#### update

I receive this error from console of browser when visiting `login` or any page includes `app.blade.php`

[image]

## Update

I updated the script codes as below

```
    <script src="http://{{ Request::getHost() }}:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

        window.Echo = new Echo({
         broadcaster: 'socket.io',
         host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
         });

        window.Echo.channel('test-event')
            .listen('.ExampleEvent', (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    </script>
```

The console still report error

> TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: laravel-echo

## update

I run

```
npm run development -- --watch
```

and this is the result

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>       "--watch"

```
'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/
setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mamad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-05T14_59_30_604Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mamad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-05T14_59_30_697Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you built your application with “npm run build”? Also, your error lookup yields [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394841/cannot-find-module-laravel-echo)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov the statement “npm run build” wasn't in that tutorial, and so I didn't do it.

Comment: It wasn’t, but it was (sort of) in the comments section. Authors often go through first few to check for valuable information for amending the article ;). In there was also some other useful things as well.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I added an update to the question

Comment: I believe you are missing the point: your Javascript/Typescript in blade file does not get compiled or treated as part of Javascript compilation through NPM. It should be eventually in the app.js that IS compiled, and through that compilation your import statement gets processed. I’ll try doing a full installation on blank slate Laravel and post an answer with walkthrough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Altogether this what is required:

1. Default Laravel installation
2. composer require predis/predis
3. Installation of NPM modules (laravel-echo-server, socket.io & laravel-echo)
4. Set up Laravel Echo Server through console (mostly default settings, except for domain name):
   `{
   "authHost": "http://echo",
   "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
   "clients": [
       {
           "appId": "fc3de97a1787ea04",
           "key": "ecf31edced85073f7dd77de1588db13b"
       }
   ],
   "database": "sqlite",
   "databaseConfig": {
       "redis": {},
       "sqlite": {
           "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
       }
   },
   "devMode": true,
   "host": null,
   "port": "6001",
   "protocol": "http",
   "socketio": {},
   "secureOptions": 67108864,
   "sslCertPath": "",
   "sslKeyPath": "",
   "sslCertChainPath": "",
   "sslPassphrase": "",
   "subscribers": {
       "http": true,
       "redis": true
   },
   "apiOriginAllow": {
       "allowCors": true,
       "allowOrigin": "http://echo:80",
       "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
       "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
   }
   }`
5. Setup of Redis Server and connecting to it with Laravel broadcasting.php file

`'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'redis')`

or BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis in .env file

6. Adding route in web.php

`Route::get('/test-broadcast', function(){
    broadcast(new \App\Events\ExampleEvent);
    return response('OK');
});`

7. Adding code in bootstrap.js:

> import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
>
> window.io = require('socket.io-client');
>    window.Echo = new Echo({
>       broadcaster: 'socket.io',
>       host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
>       });

**ADDED**

> window.Echo.channel('MyChannel')
>      .listen('.ExampleEvent', (e) => {
>          console.log(e);
>      });

8. Running `npm run dev` to compile all Javascript modules
9. Running `laravel-echo-server start` to start Laravel Echo Server
10. Running `php artisan queue:listen --tries=1` to start the listen queue
11. Accessing the http://echo/test-broadcast

**UPDATED**

11.1 Adjust methods for the ExampleEvent to:

> public function broadcastOn()
>     {
>        return new Channel('MyChannel');
>     }
>
> public function broadcastAs()
>     {
>         return 'ExampleEvent';
>     }

11.2 In welcome.blade.php, before BODY tag, add

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>`

11.3 in database.php, set redix prefix to empty string value

`'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', '')`

**DO NOT FORGET TO RE-RUN `npm run dev` and clear browser cache**

**Results**

[image: Queue running]

[image: Laravel Echo Server console results]

[image: Client & Server alongside]

Comment: Question: Do I need to setup `echo` every time I run the `xampp` and localhost? and about your answer, I got the same response `Ok` when visiting the `test-broadcast` page. But I think you missed something, The result `Ok`  is because of `return response('ok');`, But I need to tell the client about something in server side. For example If a user visits `/login`, I need to print something in console  in `test-broadcast` page. Your example will not inform the `test-broadcast` page about things happen in server.

Comment: I am not aware of any additional requirements you may have, they are up to you, I’ve only added response 200 as an example. Echo is a local domain, you can replace it with any other domain name, be it localhost or any other.

Comment: Did you include `bootstrap.js` in any of the blade files?

Comment: You didn't send any response from server to client to notify it of any changes

Comment: I've updated the answer, please see additional changes that need to be added.

Comment: I am testing, Which `bootstrap.js` you have altered? The one in `/resources/js`?

Comment: Correct, that’s the one. I’ve only been working with it anyway.

Comment: I updated the question with `npm run development -- --watch
`

Comment: I believe this can be looked up on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%27cross-env%27+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C) or [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%27cross-env%27+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C&oq=%27cross-env%27+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command)

Comment: I did that but I still get the error `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: laravel-echo` despite of all the things I did based on your answer

Comment: I found it, I shouldn't have to include `bootstrap.js` directly! it is enough to include `public/js/app.js` :|

Answer (score 1):

From your bug, I think your packages are not installed or are imported incorrectly. You can try install package

```
npm install --save socket.io-client laravel-echo
```

Add those code to end of *fileresources/js/bootstrap.js*

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

and run `npm run watch`

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites part socket.io

Comment: I updated the question with result of npm run development -- --watch

Comment: run `npm install` before to install all needed packages included `cross-env`